# Dynamically load component in Angular 9

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I load some of my components dynamically, which is super easy now with Angular 9

```
const output = import(`./components/foo/foo.component`)
  .then(({ FooComponent }) => FooComponent);
```

However, in my case, the number of these lazy components will increase, so I would like to do something like this

```
const output = import(`./components/${name}/${name}.component`)
  .then(output => output[determineComponentName(name)]);
```

However, if you do this, there is no way angular can determine during build time which components to create a separate bundle/file for. Is there maybe some way to tell angular which components these are during build time?

Comment: You should use dedicated pattern for all your dynamic components, e.g `import('./components/dynamic/${name}/${name}.component')` https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import From docs `For example, import(`./locale/${language}.json`) will cause every .json file in the ./locale directory to be bundled into the new chunk`

Comment: Thanks a lot, your suggestions works. I only needed to add `src/app/components/dynamic/**/*component.ts` to the `includes` section of **tsconfig.json**  :)